# How to get server-control id that in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I'm trying to access server control that locate inside GridView, but I dont have idea how to do that..
Here is my try:

```
<asp:GridView ....
.....
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      ...
      ..
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName"runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="edit" ItemStyle-CssClass="td" 
                       HeaderStyle-CssClass="listtitle">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" 
                         AlternateText="edit" ImageUrl="~/css/images/edit-icon.png" />
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" 
                        OnClientClick="javascript:return isValid('<%= txtName.ClientID%>')" /> | 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" 
                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    ...
    ..
  </Columns>
  .....
  ....
</asp:GridView>
```

The problem is in here

```
OnClientClick="javascript:return isValid('<%= txtName.ClientID%>')"
```

When it gets to the isValid function I see the string "<%= txtName.ClientID%>" and not the actual controller id as I should..

So the question is how can I send the id to the JS script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ibrams answer would have been correct if it was the fields are on `ItemTemplate`. But this won't work when you are on `EditItemTemplate` one have to check the `RowState` also. The condition will be something like this

```
if ((e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate)) || (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)) 
{
    //logic here
}
```

But a shorter solution will be checking this condition `GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex`

The snippet should be this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtName");
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnUpdate");
        string script = String.Format("javascript:return isValid('{0}')", btn.ClientID);
        btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On RowDataBound event you need to read the client id of your txtName and set the OnClientClick of your linkbutton.

```
void myGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtName");
        Button btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnUpdate");
        btn.OnClientClick = String.Format("javascript:return isValid('{0}')", btn.ClientID);
    }
}
```

Comment: ibram, nice solution. but you missed out the edititemtemplate part

Answer (score 0):

As you want to validate value of the txtName textBox it's much more better utilize standart asp.net validation controls. If you have some complext validation rules then you can use CustomValidator and specify javascript function for processing validation on client side. Just set the same validatio ngroup value for the validator attached to the txtName control and for the btnUpdate button.